# AWS Elastic transcoder VERY SLOW THUMBNAILS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

**Hi Folks, thanks for your help in advance.**

I have this pipeline in AWS ETS transcoding videos for months, but lately, I started to see some delay in the thumbnails for the videos.

Even web the job appears as completed in the AWS console, the thumbnails are still on their way.

Yesterday it was the total crackdown, the second thumbnail for one of the jobs took 10 hours to appear in the S3 storage.

Take a look on the screenshot.

I do not know if this is normal ( I do not think so), but Id love to get some feedback from other users using this same service before I take a drastic decision and start switching service providers.

[image: Example of AWS ETS video thumbnail creation delay]

[image: Example #2 of AWS ETS video thumbnail creation delay]

Comment: Which region are you using? When exactly did it start? Was there anything in the [status page](http://status.aws.amazon.com/)?

Comment: Hi Kichik, thanks, but the status page is the first thing I checked... I dont know, it continues to happen... it is weird and annoying, and it really annoys me the fact that I have to pay AWS premium support to talk to them... so probably, I will be cancelling the ETS with them and moving it somewhere else....

Comment: Actually, the region was US E, and the status RSS feed does not show anything since 2015: http://status.aws.amazon.com/rss/elastictranscoder-us-east-1.rss

Comment: Last test, worked fine, looks like there they had some processing delays that they fixed....   not very reliable though...

Comment: Have you tried other regions? Does it happen with all videos or just specific formats?

Comment: After months having this issue I came to no conclusion at all.   The videos are uploaded in any format and transcoded to mp4 (hd && sd) and thumbnails should be ready when the SNS is received, but sometimes they are not.

Finally I did a check in the JS code, if the image is missing trigger the exception and get another one, but the ETS is a huge bummer in this sense and we will be looking to switch to ZenCoder probably before lunch.